# snake game score

Tags: java, swing, user-interface

This snake game code. I want to add the system score in this game. So that each time the snake eating his score would be increased. But if the snake does not get food score will not increase.

How do I go about displaying the current score?

this is :

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Font;
import java.awt.FontMetrics;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.Toolkit;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.Timer;
public class Board extends JPanel implements ActionListener {

private final int WIDTH = 300;
private final int HEIGHT = 300;
private final int DOT_SIZE = 10;
private final int ALL_DOTS = 900;
private final int RAND_POS = 29;
private final int DELAY = 140;

private int x[] = new int[ALL_DOTS];
private int y[] = new int[ALL_DOTS];

private int dots;
private int apple_x;
private int apple_y;

private boolean left = false;
private boolean right = true;
private boolean up = false;
private boolean down = false;
private boolean inGame = true;

private Timer timer;
private Image ball;
private Image apple;
private Image head;


public Board() {
    addKeyListener(new TAdapter());

    setBackground(Color.black);

    ImageIcon iid = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("dot.png"));
    ball = iid.getImage();

    ImageIcon iia = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("apple.png"));
    apple = iia.getImage();

    ImageIcon iih = new ImageIcon(this.getClass().getResource("head.png"));
    head = iih.getImage();

    setFocusable(true);
    initGame();
}


public void initGame() {

    dots = 3;

    for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++) {
        x[z] = 50 - z*10;
        y[z] = 50;
    }

    locateApple();

    timer = new Timer(DELAY, this);
    timer.start();
}


public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);

    if (inGame) {

        g.drawImage(apple, apple_x, apple_y, this);

        for (int z = 0; z < dots; z++) {
            if (z == 0)
                g.drawImage(head, x[z], y[z], this);
            else g.drawImage(ball, x[z], y[z], this);
        }

        Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().sync();
        g.dispose();

    } else {
        gameOver(g);
    }
}


public void gameOver(Graphics g) {
    String msg = "Game Over";
    Font small = new Font("Helvetica", Font.BOLD, 14);
    FontMetrics metr = this.getFontMetrics(small);

    g.setColor(Color.white);
    g.setFont(small);
    g.drawString(msg, (WIDTH - metr.stringWidth(msg)) / 2,
                 HEIGHT / 2);
}


public void checkApple() {

    if ((x[0] == apple_x) && (y[0] == apple_y)) {
        dots++;
        locateApple();
    }
}


public void move() {

    for (int z = dots; z > 0; z--) {
        x[z] = x[(z - 1)];
        y[z] = y[(z - 1)];
    }

    if (left) {
        x[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
    }

    if (right) {
        x[0] += DOT_SIZE;
    }

    if (up) {
        y[0] -= DOT_SIZE;
    }

    if (down) {
        y[0] += DOT_SIZE;
    }
}


public void checkCollision() {

      for (int z = dots; z > 0; z--) {

          if ((z > 4) && (x[0] == x[z]) && (y[0] == y[z])) {
              inGame = false;
          }
      }

    if (y[0] > HEIGHT) {
        inGame = false;
    }

    if (y[0] < 0) {
        inGame = false;
    }

    if (x[0] > WIDTH) {
        inGame = false;
    }

    if (x[0] < 0) {
        inGame = false;
    }
}

public void locateApple() {
    int r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
    apple_x = ((r * DOT_SIZE));
    r = (int) (Math.random() * RAND_POS);
    apple_y = ((r * DOT_SIZE));
}

public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

    if (inGame) {
        checkApple();
        checkCollision();
        move();
    }

    repaint();
}


private class TAdapter extends KeyAdapter {

    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {

        int key = e.getKeyCode();

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) && (!right)) {
            left = true;
            up = false;
            down = false;
        }

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) && (!left)) {
            right = true;
            up = false;
            down = false;
        }

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_UP) && (!down)) {
            up = true;
            right = false;
            left = false;
        }

        if ((key == KeyEvent.VK_DOWN) && (!up)) {
            down = true;
            right = false;
            left = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: so your only question is: How do I go about displaying the current score? have you done the each time the snake eating his score would be increased. But if the snake does not get food score will not increase? more clarification on the question would help

Comment: "Swing programs should override `paintComponent()` instead of overriding `paint()`."—[*Painting in AWT and Swing: The Paint Methods*](http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/index.html#callbacks); see also this [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10965273/230513).

Answer (score 4):

You need two things:

1) Code to add the score - you should check after the move to see whether the snake's head is at the same coordinates as the apple, if so add to the score.

2) Create a JLabel to store the value of the player's score. On each timer invoked ActionPerformed, update the text of this JLabel. You won't need to worry about Multi-threading, the action event handlers invoked by the Timer are handled in a separate thread.